# ASP.NET MVC and Web Api in the same project, duplicate http response header values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, web-config

I have a ASP.NET web project with a combination of both MVC 5 and Web Api 2. The project contains a web.config file with some custom http headers defined under the system.webserver section. These headers work fine for the MVC requests, but there are some duplicate values for the Api requests.

```
<customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
    ... other headers
</customHeaders>
```

All the API request have duplicate Http headers like Cache-Control, Expires and Pragma like this.

```
Cache-Control: no cache, no cache
Expires: -1,-1
```

It seems that the Web API Framework sets these values by default. Is it possible to disable the default Api headers and use the config settings or ignore the config settings at all for Api requests? Any thoughts for a good solution?

Clearing the customHeaders elements like above or override them by removing it first before adding doens't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workaround this issue. Remove the customHeaders tag from web.config.
In your MVC 5 project, add a Custom Action Filter Attribute.

```
public class AddHeadersFilterAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("header", "headerValue");

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }
}
```

Decorate your BaseController of your MVC 5 Controllers with this Attribute. 
This should fix your issue and letting Web API 2 act like it should.